# WebLogic ClientInstanceInvocationHandler to cxf ClientProxy

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic

Hello I have a WebService Client on my java project the which is on weblogic. Now I need add the header for security reasons to my petition. I have tried everything and finally a friend help me with a code for Jboss the which works fine on Jboss, but on weblogic it gives me a problem with of castClassException.

Like the title said the original class is "ClientInstanceInvocationHandler" and I need that on "ClientProxy" of APACHE CXF

Here is the problem:

```
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient( port );
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

According to this site https://community.oracle.com/thread/2467175?tstart=0 the problem is that the Apache classes are not properly on the classpath of the server.

They said they "set the APACHE CXF jars as a User Defined Library and set it to the 'Deployed by Default' option".

In this [blog](http://avskor.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/apache-cxf-client-on-weblogic-12c.html) with the same problem, they use the following fragment in their weblogic-application.xml:

```
<prefer-application-resources>  
   <resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider</resource-name>  
 </prefer-application-resources>
```

From what I can understand weblogic returns it's own implementations for these methods unless you tell it to prefer the standard interface and put an implementation of the standard interface on the classpath.  I guess the custom class gives some extra performance or features beyond the standard interface.

The Apache CXF [site](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html#ApplicationServerSpecificConfigurationGuide-WebLogic) itself addresses this in a similar way, but suggests a different package name (javax.jws.*)

In addition to all this, some people had problems getting weblogic to find and recognise the jars because it was loading weblogic classes in preference and had to do the following:

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```

But I have seen variations on this, depending on where your Apache jars are located.